# How can I redirect product url to category then product url?

Tags: url-rewriting

Im having an issue with some product urls on my site, I have all the products in categories and sub categories, but for some reason you can still access the product directly.

```
example.com/product1
```

when Ideally it needs to be redirected to

```
example.com/cat1/sub1/product1
```

I have my permalink settings to have the `/%product_cat%` but that didn't work, the product itself belongs to `cat1`, `sub1` if that makes a difference.

Im dealing with over 500 products here, and the last thing I want to do is manually do a 301 from `/product1` to `/cat1/sub1/product1`

If there is a quick bit of code I can add to the `htaccess` file that would be awesome.

**UPDATE**

https://www.pinkdynamite.co.uk/super-strap-super-sheet/

should goto

https://www.pinkdynamite.co.uk/bondage/sexy-bedding/super-strap-super-sheet/

but not specifically this product all products should redirect to there category url or show the full category in the URL not just the product name.

Comment: what is `product1`, a custom post type?

Comment: No its a single product page.

Comment: so it's the `page` post type?

Comment: no it uses the single-product.php template

Comment: so it is a custom post type. please add the code you use to register the post type to your question.

Comment: its not a custom post type its the woocommerce product single template file.

Comment: Woocommerce products are a custom post type. This is probably something you will need to ask Woocommerce support, 3rd party plugins are off-topic here.